# Discord OAauth2 - Invalid OAuth2 redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm trying to access the user's name, avatar, and what servers they're in, but I get a weird error.
Here's the code where I think it orginiated from:

```js
const DiscordStrategy = require("passport-discord").Strategy;
const passport = require("passport");

passport.use(
  new DiscordStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.CLIENT_REDIRECT,
      scope: ["identify", "guilds"],
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      done(null, {
        discordId: profile.id,
        username: profile.username,
        guilds: profile.guilds,
      });
    }
  )
);
```

If you need more then that just comment and I'll edit.
Here's the site https://pulsebot-dashboard.herokuapp.com/

Comment: You need to register the redirectUri in Discord, have you done that? does the RedirectURl sent to Discord match the one in discord?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Discord OAuth2 redirect\_uri component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093082/issue-with-discord-oauth2-redirect-uri-component)